# Using React in only one part of a multi-page application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I already have a multi-page website which currently has two tools built with Node.js, Express, MongoDB, vanilla JS. Each tool has its own web page. I want to add a third tool on my website. This new tool will be built using React.

The main "App" component should have a "Top", "Body" and "Bottom" component. However, when I try to import these components into the App file, the content does not show.

App component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Top from './Top/Top.js';
import Body from './Body/Body.js';
import Bottom from './Bottom/Bottom.js';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Top />
                <Body />
                <Bottom />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Top component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Top extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div>Top goes here</div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Top;
```

Body component and Bottom component are similar to Top.

When I import the components into the App, the content does not show. However, if I do not import and write all the components in one file, the content shows.

I would like to separate the components into separate files as shown above for easier readibility and navigation.

Furthermore, when I try to import the components into the main App component, I also get this error in the Chrome web developer console:

[image: error]

How can I separate my components into separate files and import them correctly where needed without errors?

Thanks!

Edit: this is my webpack configuration

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/js/birdApp/birdApp.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { 
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                            },                                                      
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                     },
                     { 
                         loader: 'postcss-loader',
                         options: {
                             ident: 'postcss',
                             plugins: () => [
                                 autoprefixer({})
                             ]
                         }
                      }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Edit2: my package.json file

```
  "name": "rstools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/app.js --ext js,hbs,css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.11",
    "osrs-json-api": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this app built with Create React App?

Comment: @Luke, no. I just want to add React to one new tool on my website.

Comment: It makes me think that it might have something to do with your webpack config as that is what is looking after things like imports.

Comment: Is there any reference to set up webpack correctly for a multi page application which only needs a bit of React?

Comment: The multipage aspect doesn't really matter when it comes to webpack (or react in general). The only thing that changes is the fact that the element you're rendering to isn't at the root of the website itself, but rather on an individual page. Your webpack config is only meant to bundle your js(x) together in to (in your case) probably a singular .js file. Can you show us your webpack config file?

Comment: @technicallynick I have edited the post and added my webpack config

Comment: share your package.json file

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni i have added my package.json file

Comment: I'm not seeing anything immediately wrong with either your webpack config or your package.json. Perhaps you could set up a repro in codesandbox?